# Access Local SMS Data in the Application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I want to access all of the message text body so I can store it in some file.
Like I have stored the address book in csv file and when I press the restore button at that time particular csv data I set in the address book.
Is it possible in iPhone to access that way SMS data in the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, there is no public API for accessing the message app.

Comment: On jailbroken phones you can access the database but no public API